# Replace any string in columns with 1

Tags: python, replace, pandas

I'm working with pandas. My goal is to convert several columns within a dataframe from containing either NaN or string data, into more or less a dummy variable (0's for NaN; 1's for any string). I'd like to do this without using a complete list of strings and replacing them each, because there are typos and this would lead to errors. I've been able to replace all the NaN data with 0's using the fillna function, which works like a dream!

I am hoping for something similar that will replace all string data with 1's, but leave the 0's in place. I've searched stackoverflow and elsewhere, to little avail.

The data look roughly like this, where I only want this to apply to columns starting with T_:

```
    fol    T_opp    T_Dir    T_Enh   Activity
    1      0        0        vo      hf
    2      vr       0        0       hx
    2      0        0        0       fe
    3      0        bt       0       rn
```

I'd like the output to look the same, but with "vr" "bt" and "vo" each replaced with the integer 1. From what I can tell, the pd get_dummies function is not what I'm looking for. I also can't make this work with replace(). I tried something using a T/F mask and a list of zeros, but the outcome was so wrong I won't bother to post the code here.

Edited: I've added an additional column in the toy data above. The 'Activity' column is some data, also strings, that I do not want to touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to do this the other way around, first convert to numeric:

```
In [11]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[11]: 
   fol  T_opp  T_Dir  T_Enh Activity
0    1      0      0    NaN       hf
1    2    NaN      0      0       hx
2    2      0      0      0       fe
3    3      0    NaN      0       rn
```

And then fill in the NaNs with 1:

```
In [12]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).fillna(1)
Out[12]: 
   fol  T_opp  T_Dir  T_Enh Activity
0    1      0      0      1       hf
1    2      1      0      0       hx
2    2      0      0      0       fe
3    3      0      1      0       rn
```

Comment: In this answer, are the NaN's substituted for the strings during object conversion?

Comment: @M.A.Kline Yes they are.

Comment: @M.A.Kline updated with your new/different DataFrame.

Comment: Darn. I was *really* hoping that I could outdo you with `replace` :( Guess not :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud haha, convert_objects is *very* magical! (Your effort deserved the accept! :p)

Comment: Update: I've combined this solution with using a dict to apply the fillna method as suggested here. I wouldn't have known how to use zip to create a handy dict, though, so the answer is rather split between the two of you. Either way, learned a ton from this so thanks.

Comment: Hm. Though I had this solved, but when I use convert_objects, none of the strings are replaced with NaN. @AndyHayden any ideas? (
I don't get any error messages)

Comment: @M.A.Kline That's strange, without seeing the data it's hard to say why, can you link to the data/a toy example where this fails? (Perhaps it's worth asking a new question about this not working in this specific case with a toy example where this doesn't work?)

Comment: Agreed, I'll post a new question on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `DataFrame.replace()` with a regular expression:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   fol T_opp T_Dir T_Enh
0    1     0     0    vo
1    2    vr     0     0
2    2     0     0     0
3    3     0    bt     0

In [15]: df.replace(regex={'vr|bt|vo': '1'}).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[15]:
   fol T_opp T_Dir T_Enh
0    1     0     0     1
1    2     1     0     0
2    2     0     0     0
3    3     0     1     0
```

If for some reason you're against `dict`s, you can be very explicit about it too:

```
In [19]: df.replace(regex='vr|bt|vo', value='1')
Out[19]:
   fol T_opp T_Dir T_Enh
0    1     0     0     1
1    2     1     0     0
2    2     0     0     0
3    3     0     1     0
```

But wait there's more! You can specify the columns you want to operate on by passing a nested `dict` (keys *cannot* be regular expressions, well, they can but it won't do anything except return the frame):

```
In [22]: df.replace({'T_opp': {'vr': 1}, 'T_Dir': {'bt': 1}})
Out[22]:
   fol T_opp T_Dir T_Enh
0    1     0     0    vo
1    2     1     0     0
2    2     0     0     0
3    3     0     1     0
```

**EDIT:** Since you to replace all strings with the number `1` (as per your comments below) do:

```
In [23]: df.replace(regex={r'\D+': 1})
Out[23]:
   fol T_opp T_Dir T_Enh
0    1     0     0     1
1    2     1     0     0
2    2     0     0     0
3    3     0     1     0
```

**EDIT:** Microbenchmarks might be useful here:

Andy's method (faster):

```
In [11]: timeit df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).fillna(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 590 µs per loop
```

`DataFrame.replace()`:

```
In [46]: timeit df.replace(regex={r'\D': 1})
1000 loops, best of 3: 801 µs per loop
```

If you have columns containing strings that you want to keep

```
In [45]: cols_to_replace = 'T_opp', 'T_Dir', 'T_Enh'

In [46]: d = dict(zip(cols_to_replace, [{r'\D': 1}] * len(cols_to_replace)))

In [47]: d
Out[47]: {'T_Dir': {'\\D': 1}, 'T_Enh': {'\\D': 1}, 'T_opp': {'\\D': 1}}

In [48]: df.replace(d)
Out[48]:
   fol T_opp T_Dir T_Enh Activity
0    1     0     0     1       hf
1    2     1     0     0       hx
2    2     0     0     0       fe
3    3     0     1     0       rn
```

Yet another way is to use `filter` and join the results together after replacement:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   fol T_opp T_Dir T_Enh Activity
0    1     0     0    vo       hf
1    2    vr     0     0       hx
2    2     0     0     0       fe
3    3     0    bt     0       rn

In [11]: filtered = df.filter(regex='T_.+')

In [12]: res = filtered.replace({'\D': 1})

In [13]: res
Out[13]:
  T_opp T_Dir T_Enh
0     0     0     1
1     1     0     0
2     0     0     0
3     0     1     0

In [14]: not_filtered = df[df.columns - filtered.columns]

In [15]: not_filtered
Out[15]:
  Activity  fol
0       hf    1
1       hx    2
2       fe    2
3       rn    3

In [16]: res.join(not_filtered)
Out[16]:
  T_opp T_Dir T_Enh Activity  fol
0     0     0     1       hf    1
1     1     0     0       hx    2
2     0     0     0       fe    2
3     0     1     0       rn    3
```

Note that the original order of the columns is not retained.

You can use regular expressions to search for column names, which might be more useful than explicitly constructing a list if you have many columns to keep. The `-` operator performs set difference when used with two `Index` objects (`df.columns` is an `Index`).

You'll probably need to call `DataFrame.convert_objects()` afterward unless your columns are mixed string/integer columns. My solution assumes they are all strings so I call `convert_objects()` to coerce the values to `int` `dtype`.

Comment: Right, so I understand how to use the replace() option, but as I said above I'm hoping to find some solution that will replace *any string*... This is because the above data is only a small chunk, I actually have upwards of about 50 strings to replace with 1's. I suppose I could type them all in, but the list of strings may change as I edit my selection criteria (for munging the data). Basically I am looking for the equivalent to "search & replace all strings with 1's"

Comment: so just match anything that's not a number with the regex `\D`

Comment: I think i've just found a buglet .... seems like `\D` is matching the whole string, not just a character.

Comment: This gets the job done, except that I need to apply it to only 6 of the many columns in my dataframe. I should have made it more clear above that there are additional columns containing strings that I don't need to replace. How would I do that?

Comment: Also, since I really want to understand this, would you suggest I check out the regex documentation and the replace documentation? Anything else?

Comment: Replace docs are fairly complete....I wrote the regex functionality of `replace`, so feel free to ask me qusetions

Comment: @M.A.Kline I've added an answer for replacing a subset of columns

Comment: You *could* do this with `DataFrame.filter()` and then join the replaced columns with the not-replaced but that seems like it might be a bit inefficient and is also more complicated to understand...want me to put it up?

Comment: Clever! Out of curiosity, why does the list multiplication result in '\\D' rather than '\D' ? Since this is working I don't *need* the .filter() method, but I'd still appreciate seeing it.

Comment: Because the `r'\D'` escapes the backslash automatically. In this case, it isn't necessary because `'\D'` isn't a special character outside of regexs. So, typing `'\D'` and `r'\D'` in Python will give you the same thing. Typing `r'\t'` and `'\t'` will give you different results.