# Pandas: how to use convert_objects to replace strings with NaN values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is related to a previous question I've asked, here: [Replace any string in columns with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191832/replace-any-string-in-columns-with-1)

However, since that question has been answered long ago, I've started a new question here. I am essentially trying to use convert_objects to replace string values with 1's in the following dataframe (abbreviated here):

```
 uniq_epoch     T_Opp     T_Eval
 1              0         0
 1              0         vv.bo
 2              bx        0
 3              0         0
 3              vo.bp     0
 ...
```

I am using the following code to do this. I've actually tried using this code on the entire dataframe, and have also applied it to a particular column. The result each time is that there is no error message, but also no change to the data (no values are converted to NaN, and the dtype is still 'O').

```
 df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)
```

or

```
 df.T_Eval = df.T_Eval.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Desired final output is as follows:

```
 uniq_epoch     T_Opp     T_Eval
 1              0         0
 1              0         1
 2              1         0
 3              0         0
 3              1         0
 ...
```

Where there may also be a step prior to this, with the 1s as NaN, and fillna(1) is used to insert 1s where strings have been.

I've already searched posts on stackoverflow, and looked at the documentation for convert_objects, but it is unfortunately pretty sparse. I wouldn't have known to even attempt to apply it this way if not for the previous post (linked above).

I'll also mention that there are quite a few strings (codes) in these columns, and that the codes can recombine, so that to do this with a dict and replace(), would take about the same amount of time as if I did this by hand.

Based on the previous post and the various resources I've been able to find, I can't figure out why this isn't working - any help much appreciated, including pointing towards further documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is on 0.13.1

docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html?highlight=convert_objects#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects)
and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#object-conversion)

Maybe you have an older version; IIRC `convert_objects` introduced in 0.11.

```
In [5]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+',index_col=0)

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
            T_Opp T_Eval
uniq_epoch              
1               0      0
1               0  vv.bo
2              bx      0
3               0      0
3           vo.bp      0

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [7]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[7]: 
            T_Opp  T_Eval
uniq_epoch               
1               0       0
1               0     NaN
2             NaN       0
3               0       0
3             NaN       0

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [8]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
Out[8]: 
T_Opp     float64
T_Eval    float64
dtype: object

In [9]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).fillna(1)
Out[9]: 
            T_Opp  T_Eval
uniq_epoch               
1               0       0
1               0       1
2               1       0
3               0       0
3               1       0

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I updated to Pandas 0.13.1 and convert_objects functions as expected. (Unfortunately it causes problems for other portions of my code using drop_duplicates). Just an FYI for anyone who comes across this post.